# can't access certain web sites using Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, firefox, google-chrome

I can't access certain web site like:

www.last.fm

when I try to load any page on this site it starts with [Connecting..] in the tab title and the browser shows the [waiting for www.last.fm ..] message on the bottom left of the page, and then the browsers stops trying to load the page because the connection is timed out.

this is new problem (I was able to access it weeks ago, but something went wrong somewhere).

and it's not because this web site is now blocked by my service provider, because I can access it on my mobile device and on other (windows operated PC).

and it isn't a web browser problem, because I can't access it on both Firefox & Chrome.

is there any suggestion?

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if you Firefox adding folder is still there? Chromium and Firefox share a plugin folder, it could be corrupted or missing and the problem could be flash player not running.

Also check the App Store and see if you have flash installed. If so try uninstalling it then reinstalling. This is the only issue I could think of please comment if it works.

Comment: what folder is it you mentioned at the beginning of your post?

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Wallad.
Try the following: - open your Banshee application. In the left pane you should see:
                                                         - media online.
                   - go down to Last.fm, click it. It should open a window asking you to:
                                                    1.- Account Settings
                                                    2.- Join Last.fm
                   - make your choice and read further what to do...
                   - p.s.: notice the warning you get (in the right pane) when you click
                           Last.fm (in the left pane).

Comment: well, I have to login using the browser in order to be logged in within Banshee (in other words.. Banshee loads the last.fm login -or sigunp- pages using firefox).. but thanks anyway